# KeyError: '1' after zip method - following learning pyspark tutorial

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I'm following "Learning PySpark" tutorial (at [this link](https://github.com/PacktPublishing/Learning-PySpark/blob/master/Chapter04/LearningPySpark_Chapter05.ipynb)).
When I run

```
selector = ft.ChiSqSelector(4).fit(births_train)

s1 = births_train.map(lambda row: row.label)
s2 = selector.transform(births_train.map(lambda row: row.features))

print(s1.take(1))
print(s2.take(1))
print(type(s1))
print(type(s2))
```

I have this output:

> [0.0]
>
> [DenseVector([0.0, 99.0, 99.0, 999.0])]
>
> < class 'pyspark.rdd.PipelinedRDD' >
>
> < class 'pyspark.rdd.RDD'>

When I try to merge the results with zip, like the tutorial suggests:

```
s3=s1.zip(s2)
print(type(s3))
print(s3.collect())
```

I get this error:

> < class 'pyspark.rdd.RDD'>
>
> --------------------------------------------------------------------------- Py4JJavaError                             Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in ()
>         1 s3=s1.zip(s2)
>         2 print(type(s3))
>   ----> 3 print(s3.collect())
>
> /content/spark-2.3.1-bin-hadoop2.7/python/pyspark/rdd.py in
>   collect(self)
>       832         """
>       833         with SCCallSiteSync(self.context) as css:
>   --> 834             sock_info = self.ctx._jvm.PythonRDD.collectAndServe(self._jrdd.rdd())
>       835         return list(_load_from_socket(sock_info, self._jrdd_deserializer))
>       836
>
> /content/spark-2.3.1-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py
>   in **call**(self, *args)    1255         answer =
>   self.gateway_client.send_command(command)    1256         return_value
>   = get_return_value(
>   -> 1257             answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)    1258     1259         for temp_arg in temp_args:
>
> /content/spark-2.3.1-bin-hadoop2.7/python/pyspark/sql/utils.py in
>   deco(*a, **kw)
>        61     def deco(*a, **kw):
>        62         try:
>   ---> 63             return f(*a, **kw)
>        64         except py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError as e:
>        65             s = e.java_exception.toString()
>
> /content/spark-2.3.1-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py
>   in get_return_value(answer, gateway_client, target_id, name)
>       326                 raise Py4JJavaError(
>       327                     "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}.\n".
>   --> 328                     format(target_id, ".", name), value)
>       329             else:
>       330                 raise Py4JError(
>
> Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling
>   z:org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.collectAndServe. :
>   org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure:
>   Task 0 in stage 308.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task
>   0.0 in stage 308.0 (TID 8596, localhost, executor driver): org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent
>   call last):   File
>   "/content/spark-2.3.1-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py",
>   line 230, in main
>       process()   File "/content/spark-2.3.1-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py",
>   line 225, in process
>       serializer.dump_stream(func(split_index, iterator), outfile)   File
>   "/content/spark-2.3.1-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py",
>   line 324, in dump_stream
>       self.serializer.dump_stream(self._batched(iterator), stream)   File
>   "/content/spark-2.3.1-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py",
>   line 139, in dump_stream
>       for obj in iterator:   File "/content/spark-2.3.1-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py",
>   line 313, in _batched
>       for item in iterator:   File "", line 1, in    File
>   "/content/spark-2.3.1-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py",
>   line 75, in 
>       return lambda *a: f(*a)   File "/content/spark-2.3.1-bin-hadoop2.7/python/pyspark/util.py", line 55,
>   in wrapper
>       return f(*args, **kwargs)   File "", line 9, in recode KeyError: '1'

Why?

Comment: A `KeyError` usually means the key doesn't exist.

Comment: I reproduced all the code in the link: they don't set keys. In the simple `zip` method documentation, they don't set a key: `>>> x = sc.parallelize(range(0,5))
>>> y = sc.parallelize(range(1000, 1005))
>>> x.zip(y).collect()` gives no error. In this case, Spark sets automatically a key? Maybe is my rdd objects that have someting wrong?

Comment: If you do this in one call -- do you get an error as well? I mean, if you were to do this `topFeatures_train = (births_train.map(lambda row: row.label).zip(selector.transform(births_train.map(lambda row: row.features)))).map(lambda row: reg.LabeledPoint(row[0], row[1]))`?

Comment: When I run your command, It doesn’t give me any error. Anyway It does when I run topFeatures_train.take(1)

Comment: I noticed that, too. I just literally created an RDD: `labels = sc.parallelize([0,1,0,0,1])` and another with DenseVectors (`ln` is `pyspark.mllib.linalg`): `features = sc.parallelize([ln.DenseVector([2,3,1]) for _ in range(5)])` and run the `labels.zip(features).collect()` with no issues. How do you create `births_train`?

Comment: @TDrabas: I followed all the steps showed here https://github.com/PacktPublishing/Learning-PySpark/blob/master/Chapter04/LearningPySpark_Chapter05.ipynb

Comment: Can you run `collect()` on s1 and s2 without any error?

Comment: Yes `s1.collect()` and `s2.collect()` run normally

Comment: I start to wonder if this is Spark 2.3.1 specific issue. I tested my code in 2.3.0 and it works fine. Would you have means to run it in 2.3.0? What is the output if you run `births_train.take(1)`?

Comment: Yes, You are right! The problem was the 2.3.1. I wonder why...

Answer (score 0):

The following code works for me, although I don't know why:

```
truth = sc.parallelize(births_test.map(lambda row: row.label).collect())
prediction = sc.parallelize(LR_Model.predict(births_test.map(lambda row: row.features)).map(lambda x: x * 1.0).collect())
LR_results = truth.zip(prediction)
```

Comment: Well, it's better than nothing.